# iOS - Issues cropping an image to a detected face

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, crop, face-detection

I am trying to crop a `UIImage` to a face that has been detected using the built-in `CoreImage` face detection functionality.  I seem to be able to detect the face properly, but when I attempt to crop my `UIImage` to the bounds of the face, it is nowhere near correct.  My face detection code looks like this:

```
-(NSArray *)facesForImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    NSDictionary *opts = @{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh};

    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:context options:opts];
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage];

    return features;
}
```

...and the code to crop the image looks like this:

```
-(UIImage *)imageCroppedToFaceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index forImage:(UIImage *)image {
    NSArray *faces = [self facesForImage:image];
    if((index < 0) || (index >= faces.count)) {
        DDLogError(@"Invalid face index provided");

        return nil;
    }

    CIFaceFeature *face = [faces objectAtIndex:index];
    CGRect faceBounds = face.bounds;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, faceBounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return croppedImage;
}
```

I have an image with only 1 face in it I'm using for testing, and it appears to detect it with no problem.  But the crop is way off.  Any idea what could be the problem with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar issue -- transforming `CGImage` coordinates to `UIImage` coordinates -- I found [this great article](http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2012/03/coreimage-and-uikit-coordinates.html?m=1) explaining how to use `CGAffineTransform` to accomplish exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The code to convert the face geometry from Core Image to UIImage coordinates is fussy. I haven't messed with it in quite a while, but I remember it giving me fits, especially when dealing with images that are rotated.

I suggest looking at the demo app "SquareCam", which you can find with a search of the Xcode docs. It draws red squares around faces, which is a good start.

Note that the rectangle you get from Core Image is always a square, and sometimes crops a little too closely. You may have to make your cropping rectangles taller and wider.

Answer (score 0):

This class does the trick! A quite flexible and handy override of UIImage. https://github.com/kylestew/KSMagicalCrop

Answer (score 0):

Do It with this code It is worked for me.

```
CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];

//Container for the face attributes
UIView* faceContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:facePicture.frame];

// flip faceContainer on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image
[faceContainer setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];

// create a face detector - since speed is not an issue we'll use a high accuracy
// detector
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

// create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

     for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
    {
        // get the width of the face
        CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;

        // create a UIView using the bounds of the face
        UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];


        if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.leftEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.leftEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        }

        if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            RightEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.rightEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.rightEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        }

        if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.mouthPosition.x-faceWidth*0.2, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y-faceWidth*0.2, faceWidth*0.4, faceWidth*0.4)];
        }

        [view addSubview:faceContainer];

        CGFloat y = view.frame.size.height - (faceView.frame.origin.y+faceView.frame.size.height);

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(faceView.frame.origin.x, y, faceView.frame.size.width, faceView.frame.size.height);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([<Original Image> CGImage],rect);
        croppedImage  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        //----cropped Image-------//

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceView.frame.origin.x, y, faceView.frame.size.width, faceView.frame.size.height)];

        img.image = croppedImage;
```

Comment: Is there any problem with this code please tell me.